Need to identify Frost Free Faucet
Have a faucet that is very difficult to get to to do a replacement. Trying to find a brand name so I can just replace the interior parts of the faucet. Anyone recognize the logos?[![Faucet side view]

The top one is for Canadian Standard Association. I read JECO or JACO but can't find anything matching faucets.

Have you tried taking it apart yet?  You don't state what the problem is, I assume it leaks a little bit.  If that's the case you might find the seal on the end of the long rod is a standard size washer that can be replaced.

I tried several letter combinations for the logo and did not come up with anything useful. There is a Wolverine Brass WBCO??? but they do not list outfoor or frost free on any of their products. Tried WECO,, but they only make sinks.

Havn't taken it apart yet, will try that next ime I am there.... it is at a cottage 4 hours away from me.

Since are both knowledgeable on these things, let me toss one other question at you. On the home front I have Woodford Frost Free spigots. Installed repair kits in both of the ones I have.  When I use an outdoor faucet I turn it all the way on, or all the way off until they cannot be turned any further. That works on one of them. The other I turn all the way off till it can't be turned. But when turning it on, it just keeps on turning and never reaches a point where it stops turning. Just kind of strange. Any ideas of what I missed? Thanks for any suggestions.
